# Blasphemy that flow out of mouth

Tags: blasphemy

Please, I need help. when I did not know what blasphemy was, blasphemy would flow out of my mouth when I was angry and I would not intend to blaspheme, am I a kafir and since I realized that I did it, I kept crying to allah to forgive me. I am also 14 year old and just reached puberty.

Answer (score 0):

Blasphemy is kufr if you really meant what you said or a sin if you said it in anger. You said it was the latter.

Sin is not good but repetence is always possible (even repetence from kufr is possible). You already asked Allah to forgive you. He will. He is the All-Merciful. He promised Jannah to those who believe and do good deeds. Do so, and you will be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

**No.** Since you have cried when repenting, let's say your repentance was accepted. No one can call you kafir because you have repented.

The door of repentence is always open. Allah is the greatest forgiver.

You can try asking to forgiven to Allah again.